# How to align a view's baseline to another view's top in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Card view and I want to align another view (Red view in picture)'s center to top of the Card like in the picture.

[image]

How do I do it? The code for the Card is like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CardDemo()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CardDemo() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.LightGray),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(15.dp),
            elevation = 10.dp,
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)
            ) {
                Text("Card Title")
                Text("Card Subtitle")
                Text("Card Content Line 1")
                Text("Card Content Line 2")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    ComposeDemoTheme {
        CardDemo()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `Box`

You need your overlay view be on top of `Card` otherwise it'll be cut, so place `Card` inside `Box`. Also you can use `offset` modifier to move your view:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.LightGray),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    Box(Modifier.padding(15.dp)) {
        val textPadding = 15.dp
        val overlayBoxHeight = 20.dp
        Card(
            elevation = 10.dp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(textPadding)
            ) {
                Text("Card Title")
                Text("Card Subtitle")
                Text("Card Content Line 1")
                Text("Card Content Line 2")
            }
        }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .height(overlayBoxHeight)
                .width(40.dp)
                .offset(x = textPadding, y = -overlayBoxHeight / 2)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close to what I need. But I want red box to be over the card centered, not inside. Like in the picture I posted.

Comment: Not sure that it resolved the question of author, but it helped me in my case, thank you.

Comment: @yigitserin, then place the box outside the card. I mean inner box inside outer box scope