# How to place items in row and one each above like position absolute with JetpackCompose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to make layout that looks like this:

[image]

So I need to position two avatars in row while first avatar is going over second one. Also, icon for back is positioned on top of first avatar. I need basically something like position absolute but can not find how to do this with Jetpack compose.

Comment: have you tried `BoxWithConstaints` ? i think you can anchor the back icon with constraints or maybe [Like this with just Box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68892169/4168607). and i think your avatar must be of fixed size you can add margins for the arrangement.. not sure if there is s better way to do this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Box` and `zIndex` to reach this result,

try this code you will get a result like that

[image]

```
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Yellow)
        .padding(20.dp)
) {
    Box {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(30.dp)
                .zIndex(3f)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ArrowBack,
                contentDescription = "ArrowBack",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(20.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                    .background(Color.Gray)
                    .zIndex(2f)
                    .border(1.dp, Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                    .padding(3.dp)
            )
        }

        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 10.dp)
                .size(30.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                .background(Color.Gray)
                .zIndex(2f)
                .border(1.dp, Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                .padding(6.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Person,
                contentDescription = "Person",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(30.dp)
            )
        }
        
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 30.dp)
                .size(30.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                .background(Color.Gray)
                .zIndex(1f)
                .border(1.dp, Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                .padding(6.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Person,
                contentDescription = "Person",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(30.dp)
            )
        }
    }



    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(6.dp))
    Text(text = "17 other answers")
}
```

Comment: Not bad but still have issue because i need to use Box instead of Image in case if user does not have image i render box with background and first letter of his name. But not bad approach.

Comment: You can change `Image` with `Box` or whatever you want

Comment: Nah got issue with it if I replace it. Got some weird result with same code just Box. https://ibb.co/72xpndM

Comment: Well, that's weird, I tried to change Image to Box and I got the same result, it's working fine for me, be sure that there is no background set to the parent `Box`

Comment: Try to set background to Box that you replace with image. You will see the same :(

Comment: can you show the code, because it's working fine for me with Box and with background

Comment: Ah made it. It was just ordering issue :( ... Do you maybe have idea how to place blue icon on top of first avatar?

Comment: I edited the code, adding another Box for the blue icon, you can change `Icon` with `Image`, `Text` or even delete it, it's up to you, this should give you the result that you want